# Discord Rewrite: Client Loop Create_Task is not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a MusicPlayer that loops over a function inside the class `MusicPlayer()`. The problem is it doesn't seem to even be playing. Below is my class and the create_task is inside the `__init__` but its like it never gets ran. I have ran loops before but never in a class, is there something I am missing?

**MusicPlayer Class:**

````
class MusicPlayer():
    __slots__ = ("client", "_guild", "_ctxs", "_channel", "_cog", "np", "volume", "current", "colour")
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    next = asyncio.Event()

    def __init__(self, ctx, client):
        self.client = client
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._ctxs = ctx
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.np = None
        self.volume = defaultvolume
        self.current = None
        self.colour = self.client.defaultcolour

        self.client.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())


    async def player_loop(self):
        print('player_loop ran')
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()

        while True:
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                async with timeout(300):
                    self.current = await queue.get()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                return
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                guild = self._guild
                vc = guild.voice_client
                self.destroy(guild)
                if not vc: return
                await self._ctxs.send(":point_right: **I disconnected myself from the **`{}`** voice channel as I was not playing audio for 5 minutes!**".format(vc.channel.name))
                return
            except:
                self.destroy(self._guild)
                await self._ctxs.send(":thumbsdown: **Error: getting next song failed!** Please retry later!")
                return

            self._ctxs.voice_client.play(self.current, after=lambda: self.client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(next.set))
            self.current.volume = self.volume
            thumbnail = self.current.thumbnail if self.current.thumbnail else self.client.user.avatar_url
            self.colour = await self.client.get_average_colour(thumbnail)
            embednps = discord.Embed(colour=self.colour)
            embednps.add_field(name="Now Playing", value=f"```{self.current.title}```", inline=False)
            embednps.add_field(name="Link", value=f"[URL]({self.current.web_url})", inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Duration", value=self.client.time_from_seconds(self.current.duration), inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Channel", value=f"{self.current.uploader}", inline=False)
            embednps.set_thumbnail(url=f"{thumbnail}")
            embednps.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {self.current.requester}", icon_url=self.current.requester.avatar_url)
            self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embednps)

            await next.wait()
            print("Terminated")

            # Cleanup player
            self.current.cleanup()
            self.current = None
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an older revision of this: [Basic music with playlist support on Rewrite](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34)

You should change the create_task from:

```
self.client.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())
```

To:

```
ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())
```